# Create a Simple One-Record Form With Navigation in .aspx

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, datagrid, webforms, pagination

In C#, how do i create a new webpage that I can either use form view or data grid view, (or create a new database connection)? so that I can have a web page that will allow the user to navigate through about 50 records (one record at a time). ie; 
I am using an Access file (.mdb); which I am willing to convert if necessary.

John Smith
ID: 1
Phone: 440-202-2239

(click navigation)
(next page)

Sally Jones
ID : 2 
Phone : 440-242-2992

(click navigation)
(next page)
etc.

***THE KEY WORD TO ACCOMPLISH THIS TASK IS CALLED "PARAMETRIZED QUERIES". ****

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I'm a bit rusty, but I hope the following will lead you down the right path.

Take the following markup as an example...

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updatePane1">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="contactGrid" runat="server" EmptyDataText="No Contacts Found"  BorderStyle = "Double" AllowSorting = "true"  AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="Beige"
             EnableViewState="true" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  HeaderStyle-Height = "20" RowStyle-Height = "60" AllowPaging ="true" >
            <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Case Queue" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Black">
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass = "GridInfo"/>
                <ItemTemplate >
                        <div class="contact">Name:<%# Eval("ContactName") %></div>
                        <div class="phone">Phone:<%# Eval("PhoneNumber") %></div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView> 
    <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="30000" OnTick="Timer_Tick"> </asp:Timer>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In your loading event do something like this (note: you need to set/declare that 'data' object):

```
contactGrid.DataSource = data;
contactGrid.DataBind();
```

In the PageIndexChanging event do something like this:

```
contactGrid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
```